# Do I have to create always a new request obj, after I request.send()?

Tags: javascript, api, request

I want to create a pokedex by using pokeapi. The first 20 pokemons are stored http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon/ and the next ones in http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20   40,60..., so on.
So my problem is that I can only push the first 20 or last 20 pokemon into my Array. I think the problem lies in the request obj. 
So how can I push the first 151 Pokemon into my array ?

```
var allPages= [20,40,60,80,100,120,140];
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var allPokemon =[];

function firstPage(){
request.open('GET', 'http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon/', true);
request.onload = function () {
    var data= JSON.parse(this.response);
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    allPokemon.push(data.results[i].name);
    }
};
request.send();
}

function remaining(){
    for (var i=0;i<allPages.length;i++){
        var url = "http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon/?offset="+allPages[i];
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.onload= function(){
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
             for(var j=0; j<20; j++){
                 allPokemon.push(data.results[j].name);
             }    
        };
    }
    request.send(); 
}
firstPage();
remaining();
console.log(allPokemon);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the limit more than 20. I don't know what is the max you can get, but I can see that even 1000 is not the limit and I don't think you want this request to take a huge amount of time.

http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon/?limit="your-limit"

Comment: Tank you very much this will solve my problem. But I still dont get why my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a new XMLHttpRequest object for each HTTP request you send. The reason it isn't working is that only the first HTTP request you're attempting actually gets sent.